# running multiple instance of a function python

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, sqlite, python-2.7

I have a function readLatestOp(), the function interacts with mongodb and sqlite. I want to run multiple instance of this function concurrently to test my concurrency control mechanism. How do I go about this. So I want to call readLatestOp() maybe 10 times, running them concurrently

```
def readLatestOp():

    try:

        account = raw_input("Enter the account ID: ")
        started = time.clock()

        calSTime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        print(calSTime)
        cursor = conn.execute("select * from SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION where DEST_ID = ? AND T_COMMIT ISNULL OR SOURCE_ID = ? and T_COMMIT ISNULL", (account, account))
        result = (cursor.fetchone())
        while time.clock() - started < 5 and result is not None:

            cursor = conn.execute("select * from SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION where DEST_ID = ? AND T_COMMIT ISNULL OR SOURCE_ID = ? and T_COMMIT ISNULL", (account, account))
            result = (cursor.fetchone())

        findLatest = db.accounts.find_one({"_id" :  account})
        calFTime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        print(calFTime)
    except ValueError as err:
        print(err)
        print('You entered a wrong error')
        sys.exit(1)

    if result is not None:
        print("Data not avaialable")
    else:
        return findLatest
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
import multiprocessing

processes = []

for i in range(10):
   process = multiprocessing.Process(target=readLatestOp)
   processes.append(process)
   process.start()

print('10 processes started.')

for process in processes:
    process.join()

print('10 processes finished.')
```

### Showcase:

```
import multiprocessing
import random
import time

def do_work(process_id):
    time.sleep( random.randint(1,10) )
    print '1 from process:', process_id
    time.sleep( random.randint(1,10) )
    print '2 from process:', process_id

processes = []

for i in range(3):
   process = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_work, args=[i])
   processes.append(process)
   process.start()

print('3 processes started.')

for process in processes:
    process.join()

print('3 processes finished.')
```

### Output:

```
3 processes started.
1 from process: 2
2 from process: 2
1 from process: 1
2 from process: 1
1 from process: 0
2 from process: 0
3 processes finished.
```

Comment: How do I do it. The readLatestOp() is saved in a different file? Do I need to import it to the shell?

Comment: I am a bit new in python environment. You have written a lot of codes but I dont seem to get it. The line (target=readLatestOp), what does it do? I presume it is supposed to call the method readLatestOp() but in my case it doesnt call it.

Comment: @Conrad please see my showcase. If you have a specific question, you are welcome, if not, please read [the multiprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I seem to have seen where the error is. the (target=do_work) didnt have the parenthesis so it should be (target=do_work()). Can I do the same with running files?

Comment: @Conrad `target=do_work()` is actually *wrong*. You should **remove** the parentheses.